# How to get the correct data type with date in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**The requirements**

first_date  The first date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., month as an integer, short month name, and year as an integer).

last_date   The last date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., month as an integer, short month name, and year as an integer).

This is my code

```
 SELECT 
    To_char(min(date)::date, 'MM Mon YYYY') as first_date,
    To_char(max(date)::date, 'MM Mon YYYY') as last_date,
 FROM soloists join concerts using (id) limit 4
```

This is the output. The visual output is exactly what I want, but I don't know if it fulfils the data type requirement above. Please help me, thank you.

```
first_date       last_date
10 Oct 1980      01 Jan 2014
11 Nov 1979      12 Dec 2011
01 Jan 1980      11 Nov 2015
10 Oct 1961      06 Jun 2009
```

Comment: It is correct. The data type is `text`, but to have month short name it must be text.

Comment: As long as column `date` is of data type `date`, you are doing the right thing.

Comment: If the column `date` is already a `date` there is no need to cast it to a `date`, so `min(date)::date` can be simplified to `min(date)`

Comment: The requirement to have the month as an integer followed by the month as short name seems strange. Are you sure it shouldn't be "dd mmm yyyy"?

Comment: @FlexYourData yes, it should be "dd mmm yyyy". There is indeed a typo in the requirement.

Comment: @thanhpham, then I believe your code is producing the format of the date as described in the requirement. However, as @a_horse_with_no_name mentions, you can remove the `::date` and achieve the same result. Additionally, you may want to consider adding a grouping field that describes each row (is there a name for each soloist?). `select soloists.name, ... using (id) group by soloists.name`

Answer (score 0):

Function `to_char` return your date type on the text type and on your wanted format. If you need separately year and day on the integer type, then you can use `extract` function. Example:

```
select 
    extract(day from min(date)) as first_day, 
    extract(year from min(date)) as first_year, 
    To_char(min(date), 'Mon') as first_month
from soloists join concerts using (id) limit 4
```

On the result data fields first_day and first_year are will integer types.